# How to install active-x control from website in IE?

Tags: plugins, activex

I want to install active-x(.ocx) from website in IE.

if(active-x is not registered or installed version is old)

install/register active-x control

I am a C++ developer, I have developed active-x control(.ocx) I am new in web development.
Currently I am doing registration through (regsvr32 active-x name). I wants to automate this process. As user came to my site plugin should get installed.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the way to do it using following links:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14533/A-Complete-ActiveX-Web-Control-Tutorial
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22185/A-Complete-Scriptable-ActiveX-Web-Control-Tutorial

Thanks,
Pravin